# Why do my arrow keys not work in irb on iterm2

Tags: iterm, ruby

The arrow keys work fine in iTerm2 in general, but break in irb. Instead of working as arrow keys, they get escaped as `^[[D`, `^[[C`, etc.

Comment: Because what the arrow keys are sending, the ESC+[+[A-D], are not what that application recognizes as being the arrow keys.  Does irb use readline, or something else?  What do you have $TERM set to?

Comment: Term is se to `xterm-256color`. Yes, I believe irb uses readline by default.